# Can't open two instances of Visio 2013

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-visio-2013

I've faced with strange behavior of Visio. I'm opening two documents, but there is still one running application. And I can't move one, to another display. This is kind of annoying thing, and it slows my productivity. Is there any solutions, or it is known issue?

*P.S. I'm using Windows 8.1*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651/open-2-visio-diagrams-in-different-windows

Comment: Don't know how, but it works now with after I added registry key and rebooted machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I've followed steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7533665/1112547).

> To implement the new behavior, follow the following registry trick:
>
> 1. Open Microsoft Visio.
> 2. Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced.
> 3. Check the Put all settings in Windows Registry option.
> 4. Run Registry Editor (regedit).
> 5. Navigate to the following registry key:
>     
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Visio\Application\
> 6. In the right pane, right click on SingleInstanceFileOpen, and then select Modify. Update the value of SingleInstanceFileOpen from 1 to 0.

But key was missing on my machine, so I've just added it and rebooted machine. Now it seems work.

Answer (score 7):

Open one instance of Visio 2013 and a icon will appear in the task bar. Now hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the Visio taskbar icon (or middle-click on the icon). A new instance will open. This works for all programs not just Visio 2013.

[image: Visio 2013 2 instances running on task manager]

Comment: A middle-click will do, too. Probably also works in Metro.

Comment: @DanielB yes a middle click will do too, but it does not work in metro as I tried now.